Keyring-ui Error: Unable to initialise options more than once
GM! Im trying to initialice keyring, but for some reason its already inicialized.
This is my code:
"use client"
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from "@polkadot/api";
import { web3Accounts, web3Enable, web3FromAddress, web3FromSource } from "@polkadot/extension-dapp";
import keyring from "@polkadot/ui-keyring";
import { stringToHex } from "@polkadot/util";

const PolkadotContext = createContext();

const APP_NAME = "MV_DAPP";

export const PolkadotProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [api, setApi] = useState(null);
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);
  const [selectedAccount, setSelectedAccount] = useState();
  const [isKeyringInitialized, setIsKeyringInitialized] = useState(false);

  const loadApi = async () => {
    if(api === null) {
      const wsProvider = new WsProvider(
        "wss://xxxxxxx-rpc.a.stagenet.tanssi.network"
      );
     
      const _api = ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider }).then(() => {
        if (isKeyringInitialized === false) {
          keyring.loadAll({ ss58Format: 42, type: 'sr25519' })
          setIsKeyringInitialized(true)
        }  
      });
      setApi(_api);
    }
  }

  const handleConnect = async () => {
    const extensions = await web3Enable(APP_NAME);

    if (!extensions) {
      throw Error("No_Extension_Found")
    };

    const allAccounts = await web3Accounts();

    setAccounts(allAccounts);

    console.log(accounts);

    if (allAccounts === 1) {
      setSelectedAccount(allAccounts[0])
    }
    console.log(selectedAccount)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!api){
      loadApi();
    }
  })

  
  //NFT minting functions
  const handleCreateNFT = async () => {
    const adminAddress = selectedAccount.address;
    const injector = await web3FromAddress(adminAddress);
    const signer = await injector.signer;
    console.log(signer);
    console.log(injector)
    
    if (!api) {
      console.log("NO_API")
      loadApi();
      console.log(api)
    }

    if (!selectedAccount) {
      console.log("NO_SELECTED_ACCOUNT")
    } }

   
  
  

  const contextValue = { api, accounts, handleConnect, setSelectedAccount, selectedAccount, handleCreateNFT };

  return (
    <PolkadotContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </PolkadotContext.Provider>
  );
};


export const usePolkadot = () => useContext(PolkadotContext);

And this is the error:
index.js:36 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to initialise options more than once


Could you provide the full code? But it's clearly that you initialize the instances multiple times.

Just  added the full code in the question. Tks.
